# VBA WebBrowser capture full screen

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-8, excel, browser

Would like to do this within the confines of VBA (other users have no other development tools to modify). Am aware of 3rd party apps (iMacros, for example) that do similar but want to have this as generic as possible.  The shop uses XP and Excel 2003.

**(1)** A VBA subroutine is controlling an InternetExplorer browser to automate viewing website, form submits, etc.

**(2)** Is there a way to get a screen capture from the contents of the WebBrowser?  Without messy SendKeys approaches? .NET has a Webbrowser.DrawToBitmap method but can't find an easy solution for VBA.  Want the entire screen, including "below the fold" - below the scroll bars...

Comment: PDF any use? If so, you could print.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do it using API's but is kind of complex.

Answer (score 10):

**Paste complete code in a module and run Sub Sample()**

**CODE LOGIC**

**1)** This code will open IE

**2)** Navigate to Google.com

**3)** Maximize IE

**4)** Take snapshot

**5)** Launch MSPaint

**6)** Paste in MSPaint

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, _
ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT As Byte = 44

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal _
lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal _
nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
Private Const VK_LCONTROL As Long = &HA2
Private Const VK_V = &H56
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2

Sub Sample()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim hwnd As Long, IECaption As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    
    IE.Navigate "www.Google.com"
    
    Sleep 5000
    
    '~~> Get the caption of IE
    IECaption = "Google - Windows Internet Explorer"
    
    '~~> Get handle of IE
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, IECaption)
    
    If hwnd = 0 Then
        MsgBox "IE Window Not found!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        '~~> Maximize IE
        ShowWindow hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
    End If
    
    DoEvents
    
    '~~> Take a snapshot
    Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)
    
    '~~> Start Paint
    Shell "C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe", vbNormalFocus
          
    Sleep 3000
    
    '~~> Paste snapshot in paint
    keybd_event VK_LCONTROL, 0, 0, 0
    keybd_event VK_V, 0, 0, 0
    keybd_event VK_V, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    keybd_event VK_LCONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
End Sub
```

Comment: In my test, not quite getting the webpage only - also getting scroll bars, but it's a start. Thanks.

Comment: Yes unfortunately, you will get the snapshot of the complete screen. It's like pressing `PRINTSCREEN` after maximizing IE.

Comment: you may need to increase the screen resolution to make those scrollbars disappear :)

Comment: +1 kick-ass answer! Although to be honest, I'm currently purging all things google from my life... [go duck!](http://duckduckgo.com/) So, is `keybd_event` just an alternative to `SendKeys` that supports `PrntScrn`? (which `SendKeys` doesn't) Is it subject to the same weaknesses?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Sorry I had not seen the edit :) The most common weakness both have is sending keys to destination application requires destination application to be active. I also saw a minor error in my above post which I have rectified

Comment: @SteveValarenti: You have 2 options. Either manually crop the image in paint or you can crop it using VB (again a complex process).

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim objIe As Object
Set objIe = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With objIe
        .Navigate "www.google.com"
        '// Set offline JIC user NOT Online
        .offline = True
        '// Maximise the Ie window if not Already Max
        .Visible = True
        '// This routine used to Maximise Ie
        ShowWindow objIe.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
        SetForegroundWindow objIe.hwnd
    End With
```

> 

```
Public Const SW_MAXIMIZE As Long = 3       'Show window Maximised
Public Const SW_MINIMIZE As Long = 1       'Show window Minimized

Public Declare Function ShowWindow _
    Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal nCmdShow As Long) _
As Long

Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow _
    Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long) _
As Long
```