# IE automation VBA, delay in sending keys using sendkeys instantly

Tags: vba, excel, sendkeys, webautomation

I have written a code to take screen shots whenever webpage navigates and paste it in Word document using VBA, I succeeded in doing that but I am getting the screen shots that took last time instead of present one.

Example whenever I press printscreen it is pasting screen shot took last time instead of present one. I tried doing delays and making the argument to true, false nothing worked.

This is what I have tried in Class1 module:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WithEvents ie As InternetExplorer
Dim wordapp As Object
Dim wrdDoc As Object
Dim t As Date
Sub Example()
Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")

wordapp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wordapp.Documents.Add
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.navigate "http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~riggs/html/select_example.html"
Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
test
End Sub
Private Function href_onclick() As Boolean

Application.SendKeys "{44}"
wordapp.Selection.Paste
End Function
```

in a module

```
Sub initialise()
Set ev = New Class1
ev.Example

End Sub
```

Comment: Sendkeys is unreliable. See this link. this does what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759580/vba-webbrowser-capture-full-screen/10760645#10760645 I am pasting in MSPaint. You can paste it in word

Comment: You don't need that part. That is for pasting in PaintBrush. The image is already in the clipboard. You can use `Selection.Paste` to paste it in word.

Comment: @SiddharthRout it doesnt work, its pasting the older one even after using the keybd_event, can u pls run my code and give a solution?pls

Comment: @SiddharthRout hi, sidharth pls help me with this..

Comment: @SiddharthRout hi your solution is not working friend pls give me other solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all struggling i came up with this solution, I just made the paste option to wait for 3 secs till the picture gets loaded into the clipboard ....:)sendkeys with true option doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

try 
    Application.SendKeys "{44}", True

The Second parameter tells the execution of the code to wait for the action to complete

Comment: i have even tried Appliication.SendKeys "{44}", True even then it is working the same way, pls execute the code i gave and help me to get a solution pls, its urgent .