# How to take screenshot of webpage using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, screenshot

How to take screenshot of webpage using VBA in Excel? The problem is that screenshots can be taken only by pressing F6 key of keyboard since Screenhunter is used for this purpose. The print screen key is disabled.

I used the following code but realised that sendkey function can not be used:

```
sub test()

    application.sendkeys "{F6}"

end sub
```

Comment: I have answered a similar question. Now I am not sure whether it is here or vbforums or msdn :p Let me search for it

Comment: BTW isn't F6 for activating the address bar of the webbrowser?

Comment: Ah! Found it... See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759580/vba-webbrowser-capture-full-screen). In your case since the printscreen is not working and you want to you `F6`, change `Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)` to `Call keybd_event(VK_F6, 0, 0, 0)` and add the value of it as a const on top like I did for `VK_SNAPSHOT`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is a complete list of virtual list codes

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! It worked without changing it for F6 key. But I would like to paste it in a word document. Also, I want the focus to change back to webpage after pasting into Word document.

Comment: You need to open word instead of notepad and then paste it there

Comment: I opened a word doc. but not able to paste it there. I used Application.paste

Comment: Please post the lastest code that you are using in your question. Let me check that code

Comment: Yeah!!!! I got it.. I tried coding this thing all morning.. And now I do not know how, but it worked!!!Thanks a lot Siddharth! I shall post my code in some time.. Its entirely what u had given me, except for the last bit. where i use word to paste the screen shot

Answer (score 5):

I have added some delay after maximizing the screen, created a Word Doc and pasted the screen shot in it. The rest of the code is taken from the link which Siddharth has provided.

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT As Byte = 44

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
Private Const VK_LCONTROL As Long = &HA2
Private Const VK_V = &H56
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2

Sub Sample()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim hwnd As Long, IECaption As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True

    IE.Navigate "www.Google.com"

    Sleep 5000

    '~~> Get the caption of IE
    IECaption = "Google - Internet Explorer"

    '~~> Get handle of IE
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, IECaption)

    If hwnd = 0 Then
        MsgBox "IE Window Not found!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        '~~> Maximize IE
        ShowWindow hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
    End If
Sleep 3000
    DoEvents

    '~~> Take a snapshot
    Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)

    '~~> Start Word


    Set wordobj = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   Set objDoc = wordobj.Documents.Add

   wordobj.Visible = True

   Set objSelection = wordobj.Selection

   'Paste into Word
   objSelection.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi i have this issue today. I would like to print screen http://www.hkab.org.hk/hibor/listRates.do?lang=en&Submit=Search&year=2014&month=1&day=10 i change IE.Navigate to this link. WHile it pop out IE Window Not found! How can i achieve this? It able to load the page. While cannot print screen.

Comment: You can bypass FindWindow (which works inconsistently with tabbed browsing).  However the IE object has a .hwnd property     - so
    
    '~~> Get handle of IE
    'hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "")
    hwnd = IE.hwnd

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me when I needed to create thumbnail images of several sites.

While not "elegant", it does the job, and I think it's pretty self-explanatory.

```
Option Explicit
'requires references: "Microsoft HTML Object Library" & "Microsoft Internet Controls"

Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, _
    ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Sub getSS()
  Const url = "stackoverflow.com" 'page to get screenshot of (http is added below)
  Const fName = "x:\thumb_" & url & ".png" 'output filename (can be png/jpg/bmp/gif)
  Const imgScale = 0.25 'scale to 25% (to create thumbnail)

  Dim ie As InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet, sz As Long
  Dim img As Picture, oCht As ChartObject
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set ie = GetIE()
  With ie
    .navigate "http://" & url
    Do: DoEvents: Loop While .busy Or .readyState <> 4 'wait for page load
    ShowWindow .hwnd, 5 'activate IE window
    Call keybd_event(44, 0, 0, 0) '44="VK_SNAPSHOT"
    Pause (0.25) 'pause so clipboard catches up
    With ws
      ShowWindow Application.hwnd, 5 'back to Excel
      .Activate
      .Paste
      Set img = Selection
      With img
        Set oCht = ws.ChartObjects.Add(.Left, .Top, .Left + .Width, .Top + .Height)
        oCht.Width = .Width * imgScale 'scale obj to picture size
        oCht.Height = .Height * imgScale
        oCht.Activate
        ActiveChart.Paste
        ActiveChart.Export fName, Mid(fName, InStrRev(fName, ".") + 1)
        oCht.Delete
        .Delete
      End With
      .Activate
    End With
    .FullScreen = False
    .Quit
  End With
  If Dir(fName) = "" Then Stop 'Something went wrong (file not created)
  sz = FileLen(fName)
  If sz = 0 Then Stop 'Something went wrong! (invalid filename maybe?)
  Debug.Print "Created '" & fName & "' from '" & url & "' (" & sz & " bytes)": Beep
End Sub

Sub Pause(sec As Single)
  Dim t As Single: t = Timer
  Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Timer > t + sec
End Sub

Function GetIE() As Object
'requires references: "Microsoft HTML Object Library" & "Microsoft Internet Controls"
'return an object for the open Internet Explorer window, or create new one
  For Each GetIE In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows() 'Loop to find
    If (Not GetIE Is Nothing) And GetIE.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then Exit For 'Found!
  Next GetIE
  If GetIE Is Nothing Then Set GetIE=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'Create
  GetIE.Visible = True 'Make IE visible
  GetIE.FullScreen = True
End Function
```

Comment: 64-bit versions of the declarations: `Public Declare PtrSafe Function keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)`   
`Public Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Boolean`

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it simple:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2

Sub PrintScreen()
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0 'Key Down
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0  'Key Up
End Sub
```

And after the procedure `'PrintScreen'` is called, use 'Paste' function (for example `'Ctrl+V'` to paste the screen shot just captured into applications like Word, Excel or Paint.