# Save embedded WebBrowser as Picture - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, google-maps

I feel like I've given this problem my due diligence. So I come to you.

I have an excel file with an embedded Microsoft Web Browser. The file is a "centers of gravity" calculator. It is taking a list of addresses, geocoding them via google, then saving to an html file. The webbrowser then reimports the file with markers and icons on a google map for the centers of gravity. This aspect of the tool works great.

Now, I wish to export this map to a PowerPoint. I've already written the code to do that, but I cannot get a picture to transfer out of the webbrowser.

Below is only able to copy the shape itself, a paste on this would create another webBrowser in excel. A paste to powerpoint does nothing.

```
Thisworkbook.Activesheet.Shapes("Webbrowser1").Copy
```

Below has not worked at all, it keeps telling me "expected =" maybe this isn't even VBA..

```
webbrowser1.document.execcommand( copy false null)
```

I've tried setting the range of cells behind my webbrowser equal to a variable, then copying that variable, but to no success.

Toggling the design mode on/off does allow you to select the browser object. I've tried turning design mode off, selecting picture, copy->copyaspicture, but that didn't work either.

I don't really have a huge segment of code to work with here as the issue is pretty specific and I've basically written around it all I can.

I'm open to more out of the box solutions like getting the activewindow left/top and picture top/left and doing some sort of partial screengrab. I actually tried this too but was not successful (probably due to me).

If anyone has ideas, I would be very greatful. Spent a good 5 hours of my Friday on this one..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about the idea of tacking a screenshot?

[How to take screenshot of webpage using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580606/how-to-take-screenshot-of-webpage-using-vba)

Would that work with you application.

It would then have to be visible = true and displayalerts = true