# VBA to take screenshot of a web page, save it as file and attach it in new email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am new to the world of VBA . However I found something promising :

[How to take a screenshot of webpage using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580606/how-to-take-screenshot-of-webpage-using-vba)

It gives an idea on how to take a screenshot after opening IE.

But it doesn't tell how to save it on local machine and attach it to a new email.

How do I do that?

Edit - right now, I am using selenium and running a shell script to execute the selenium script from VBA to store it. But this would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base code for Outlook :

```
Sub test_Prateek_Narendra()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim objMsg As Object
    FilePath = StoreScreenShotFrom_As("www.google.com", "TestScrenShot", "jpg")

    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem = 0
    With objMsg
        .To = "email@email.com"
        .Subject = "Test Subject"
        .Attachments.Add FilePath
        .Display
    End With 'objMsg
End Sub
```

And the function to take the screen shot (in full-screen) and save it as a file :

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As LongLong, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)
#Else
    Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
#End If
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT As Byte = 44

Public Function StoreScreenShotFrom_As(URL_Dest As String, Img_Name As String, Img_Type As String)
    Dim IE As Object, IECaption As String
    Dim aXL As Object, aWB As Object, aSh As Object, aChO As Object, Img_Path As String
    Img_Path = VBA.Environ$("temp") & "\" & Img_Name & "." & Img_Type

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .FullScreen = True
        .Navigate URL_Dest

        '''Possibilities to wait until the page is loaded
            'Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            '    DoEvents
            'Loop
        '''OR
            'Sleep 5000
        '''OR (custom sub below)
            WasteTime 5

        '''Take a snapshot
        Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)
        DoEvents
        .Quit
    End With 'IE

    '''Start Excel
    Set aXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
        With aXL
            .WindowState = -4143 'xlNormal
            .Top = 1
            .Left = 1
            .Height = .UsableHeight
            .Width = .UsableWidth
            .WindowState = -4137  'xlMaximized
    On Error GoTo 0
            Set aWB = .Workbooks.Add
            Set aSh = aWB.Sheets(1)
            Set aChO = aSh.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, .Width, .Height)
        End With 'aXL

    With aChO
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        With .ShapeRange
            .Line.Visible = msoFalse
            .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        End With '.ShapeRange
        With .Chart
            .Export FileName:=Img_Path, Filtername:=Img_Type, Interactive:=False
        End With '.Chart
        DoEvents
        .Delete
    End With 'oChrtO
    aWB.Close False
    DoEvents
    aXL.Quit

    StoreScreenShotFrom_As = Img_Path
End Function

Private Sub WasteTime(SecondsToWait As Long)
    Dim TimeLater As Date
    TimeLater = DateAdd("s", SecondsToWait, Now)
    Do While Now < TimeLater
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It gets hung at Sleep 3000

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : Do you have an error or anything? Or does it stays stuck? Did you paste the `Private ...`s at the start of the module where the function is?

Comment: yes - pasted the Private subs are at the start of the module.. The IE opens up and made full screen.. On debugging, I wanted to see where it hangs.. It hangs at the Sleep function

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : Strange, this was working fine for me, does `Sleep` still work in the other example(link in your question)? I've commented it out and put another piece of code that should allow VBA to wait for IE to complete the loading! ;)

Comment: I'll check this out in a day or 2.. Forgot my laptop at home :P

Comment: so i tried that and it didnt work.. I wrote some other function for delaying... But now it gets stuck at aXL.WindowState = maximized

Comment: it says that its unable to set WindowState property of application class (run-time error 1004)

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : My bad, I forgot to change Excel's constants that are not recognized in Outlook if you've not added the ref! I've amended the code a bit : Changed `Sleep` or `Do While` (that should be working but seems wasn't for you) by `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))` and I've added error *handling* for the non essential part about the size of Excel (and reinforced it + late binding)! should run smoothly now! ;) Let me know! :)

Comment: Is there some reference to Include for Application.wait ? It says - object doesnt support this method or property

Comment: added my own time waster function

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : I've included your option to wait too. Do you still have a white screenshot with that code? Because it runs smoothly for me everywhere. Do you see IE opening, going in fullscreen and navigating to the webpage?

Comment: yes, it goes and navigates to the page.. Is it possible that the button for screenshot is some other button? I have a separate key on my keyboard for Print screen thats not in any Function keys.

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : It's already supposed to use that button (take a look here if you want to change the button : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx codes are in hexa but you'll easily find a way to convert it in decimal). Try to add a breakpoint on the `DoEvents` after the `Call keybd_event` and see if you can paste the image manually anywhere.

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : Do you mean that when you pasted manually, you had the good screenshot? Do you have any clipboard tool?

Comment: i just put a breakpoint after where the screenshot of the page is supposed to have been taken.. Then I went to paint and pasted  - no contents. Then i pressed print screen, it took the screenshot nd proceeded normally....

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : Ok so the issue is really on taking the screenshot. What is your OS?

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : Ok, which version (XP, 7, ...) and how many bits?

Comment: Windows 10 64 Bit. How about I use HTML5 ? Inject a bit of JS into the page which will take the screenshot?

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : Ok, there seems that there is indeed an issue in using `keybd_event` in Win10, try replacing its declaration by `Declare PtrSafe Sub Alias "keybd_event" Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, _
 ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)`.

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : Can you find `Win32API_PtrSafe` somewhere on your disk?

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : I've amended the declaration, try it and let me know! ;)

Comment: It works!! Forgot to tell that im using VBA 7 :P Small problem now - On printscreen, it takes screenshot from all 3 screens :P Can i configure it to take only the laptop screen and not the other 2 attached screens? :P

Comment: alt + printscreen is used to take screenshot of single screen

Comment: @PrateekNarendra: Glad it finally works for you! You can press Alt and then PrintScreen with keybd_event. Alt is VK_MENU=0x12=18 and see this http://vbcity.com/forums/t/28349.aspx to implement it (you'll have 4 rows of keybd_event). And a little upvote will be welcome after all the efforts! ;)

Comment: how 4 rows? I thot it had to be Call keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, VK_SNAPSHOT, 0).. Anyways - it didnt work

Comment: @PrateekNarendra Look at the 1st example in the link, You'll have to press Alt then PrintScreen and then release both, so yeah 4 lines

Comment: @R3uK- Got it m8!! Thanks.. Can i transfer 50 creds to u?

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : thx mate! You can do that only if you open a bounty on the question, but even if I'd appreciate, keep it! A little upvote will be enough! ;) And just by curiosity, did you have anything to specify which screen you want to take a picture?

Comment: I have upvoted it.. I needed to take a screenshot of a dashboard once a day and send it... I had automated it with selenium , made a jar and ran the command opening a shell from the Macro.. But some ppl had a problem with Java 8 and installation..

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : Ok, indeed, this will be simple and very portable as it is full late binding! ;) Glad I could help!

Comment: can i crop this image a tiny bit ?

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : Automatically, I'm not sure... Try by playing with the sizes of `aChO` and `aChO.Chart` or `aChO.Shapes(0)` once you've pasted the screenshot into the graph... (place a breakpoint after pasting, and use macro recorder to see what you are modifying)

Comment: awesome bro... Drinks on me when you re in Bangalore

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : ahah! Thx, maybe some day! ;) You managed to crop it like this?

Comment: In the With IE ... Block, I wanted to set the zoom to 135%..

I typed in - .zoom = 135.. It gave me an error. Is there some way to set the zoom manually?

Comment: @PrateekNarendra : Apparently, zoom is a method of window, so maybe `.Window.Zoom`... Google it, you may find how to access if it's not working! ;)

Comment: i tried - .document.body.Style.Zoom . But this makes it of bad quality

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Excel macro to save the clipboard's image into an `XPS` file:

```
Sub xlSaveClipboardImageToXPS()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Cleanup

    With Sheets.Add
        .Paste
        With .PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlLandscape: .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1: .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With
        .ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypeXPS, "C:\myScreen.xps"
        .Delete
    End With

Cleanup:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

From outlook, you can achieve it by using Excel's services, this way:

```
Sub olSaveClipboardImageToXPSUsingExcel()
    With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        With .Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1)
            .Paste
            With .PageSetup
                .Orientation = 2: .Zoom = False
                .FitToPagesWide = 1: .FitToPagesTall = 1
            End With
           .ExportAsFixedFormat 1, "C:\SO\myScreen.xps"
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Now that you have a file, the rest is Outlook folklore; you create a mail item and put the file in attachment...

Also note that you can use PDF format if you prefer, just use `ExportAsFixedFormat 0` (`xlTypePDF = 0` in Excel).