# Adding screenshots at the end of WORD Doc

Tags: excel, vba

I was going thru the following link to add the screen shots to the word doc

[How to take screenshot of webpage using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580606/how-to-take-screenshot-of-webpage-using-vba)

I did a few changes to add the screen shots to the existing document (in VBA), opening it, if not open and trying to append the screenshots at the end of the document.'

However, when the control is at the statement " .Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory", I'm facing with the

RUN TIME ERROR '4120':
BAD PARAMETER

I'm not sure what's causing this issue, could someone please help on this

```
 Set WordObj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
 Set WordDoc = WordObj.Documents.Open(StrPath & FileToOpen)  


 With WordObj
      .Selection.Goto What:=1, Which:=2, Name:=PageNumber
      .Visible = True
 End With

 Sleep 1000

 With WordObj
    .Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    .Selection.TypeParagraph
    .Selection.Paste

 End With
```

Comment: Hi, any help on this please?

Comment: I could able resolve this. after commenting out the below statement it worked fine.. "Selection.Goto What:=1, Which:=2, Name:=PageNumber"