# Visiting Multiple Links and Auto-saving Screenshots

Tags: url, screenshot, emeditor

There is something I want and I want to know if it is possible.

What I want is to visit multiple URLs and automatically save screenshots.
And if possible, the save name of the screenshot should be the same as its URL.

For example, would it be possible to do this with `Excel` or `EmEditor`?
Maybe with macro?

Is it possible to do this?
And if possible how can I do it?

**EXAMPLE:**

**URLS**: 3 Pieces (Or More)

> 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/one
> 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/two
> 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/three

Visiting these links automatically and saving screenshots as below.

**Screenshots:**

> 1. stackoverflow.com-questions-one.jpg
> 2. stackoverflow.com-questions-two.jpg
> 3. stackoverflow.com-questions-three.jpg

Note: The `HTTPS://` part may not be in the registration name, as `:` and `/` signs will not be accepted during registration.
Also the `/` symbol has been replaced with a `-` sign.

**Screenshots 2:**

> 1. questions-one.jpg
> 2. questions-two.jpg
> 3. questions-three.jpg

**Note 2**: Even if the entire URL is not the filename. Just like above.

I visited a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580606/how-to-take-screenshot-of-webpage-using-vba).
However, the information presented did not do exactly what I wanted.
I tried the sample codes provided.
For example [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56791211/16839851).

I opened an excel file and created a macro with VBA and ran it.
When the macro ran `Internet Explorer` opened and became `Full Screen`.
The page that opened was `www.google.com`.
Then the screenshot was automatically taken and saved in the `WORD` document.

This is not what I want.
Also; The [other code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21609827/16839851) in the question didn't work at all.
If the above example doesn't explain exactly what I want, please see the steps below.

> 1. Multiple URLs will be opened one by one automatically.

`(It could be Internet Explorer & Chrome or Edge or anyone.)`

> 2. The screen will be enlarged and switched to full screen mode.
>    **Note:** What I'm talking about at this point is the action performed with the <kbd>F11</kbd> key.
> 3. Wait `7 seconds` for the text **"Press the <kbd>F11</kbd> key to exit full screen"** disappears on the screen.
> 4. A screenshot will be taken and pasted into `Microsoft Paint`.
> 5. The screenshot will be saved with the URL name.
>    Sample:
>    Screenshots should be saved with the part of the current URL after `.com`.
>    The `/` sign in the links will cause problems when creating the filename.
>    Therefore, when saving the screenshot, it will be necessary to automatically replace the `/` with a `-` sign and save it as such.

**IMPORTANT**

I do not expect any service from you; I just don't have enough coding knowledge to do them.
To be frank, I do not have any information under the name of `Code Information`.
I respect the knowledge of each of you very much and I want you to know that I am sincere about it.
I'm just someone looking for a way to do what I want.

I don't expect anything from scratch on this; I'm just waiting for someone who needs help on the same issue before to share if they have any solution on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method** for Windows 7, 8.1, 10

1. Close all windows first.
2. Open your default web browser and maximize the browser window, and close the browser window.
3. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and type `SnippingTool.exe` to run the **Snipping Tool**. click `Mode` button (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) and select `Full Screen`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to show the `Save As` dialog box. I recommend creating a new folder (for example, `Scrn`), and save a screenshot in the new created folder, such as `Scrn\screenshot.png`. This is just a dummy screenshot, and you can delete it later. Doing this allows the following screenshots saved into this new same folder. Close the Snipping Tool.
4. Open the text file with a list of URLs with EmEditor. Please don't maximize the EmEditor window. I would recommend testing with a few URLs first. The text file should look like this:

```
https://www.emeditor.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://www.google.com/
```

5. Run the macro (Screenshot1.jsee) below, and please don't touch keyboard or mouse until you see `Finished saving screenshots` in a dialog box.

`Screenshot1.jsee`

```
document.selection.StartOfDocument();
nLines = document.GetLines();
for( y = 1; y <= nLines; ++y ) {
    str = document.GetLine( y );   // retrieve an URL at a line
    if( str.length != 0 ) {
        str = str.replace("http://", "");  // remove "http://" and "https://"
        str = str.replace("https://", "");
        if( str.charAt( str.length - 1 ) == '/' ) {  // remove the last slash character
            str = str.substr( 0, str.length - 1 );
        }
        str = str.replace("/", "-");   // replace invalid characters with "-"
        str = str.replace("~", "-");
        str += ".png";   // append ".png"
        
        document.selection.OpenLink();
        document.selection.LineDown(false,1);
        Sleep( 5000 );  // wait for the browser to become active and show the webpage completely

        WshShell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" );
        WshShell.Run( "SnippingTool.exe" );
        Sleep( 2000 );  // wait for the Snipping Tools appears
        shell.SendKeys( "%M" );  // Press Alt+M
        Sleep( 100 );
        shell.SendKeys( "s" );  // Press s
        Sleep( 100 );
        shell.SendKeys( "%n" );  // Press Alt+N
        Sleep( 1000 );
        shell.SendKeys( "~" );  // Press Enter
        Sleep( 100 );
        shell.SendKeys( "~" );   // Press Enter
        Sleep( 1000 );
        shell.SendKeys( "%{F4}" );  // Press Alt+F4 to close Snipping Tools
        Sleep( 1000 );
        shell.SendKeys( "y" );   // select YES
        Sleep( 1000 );
        shell.SendKeys( str + "~" );   // enter file name
        Sleep( 1000 );
        
        shell.SendKeys( "%{F4}" );  // Press Alt+F4 to close web browser
        Sleep( 1000 );
    }
}
alert( "Finished saving screenshots" );
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `Screenshots.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run Screenshots.jsee** in the **Macros** menu.

Notes: If the same file names exist in the destination folder, the macro will stop when the Snippets Tools prompts for overwrite. Please make sure the destination folder is empty or that same file names don't exist in the destination folder.

If something went wrong, you can cancel the macro by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> (or <kbd>ESC</kbd> twice consecutively) while EmEditor has the keyboard focus.

**Second Method** for Windows 10

This method should be more robust and faster than the first method.

1. First, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScrn</kbd> and make sure a screenshot is saved in your personal `Pictures/Screenshots` folder. Delete this file, and ensure the folder is empty.
2. Close all windows.
3. Open your default web browser and maximize the browser window, and close the browser window.
4. Open the text file with a list of URLs with EmEditor. Run the macro below.

`Screenshot2.jsee`

```
document.selection.StartOfDocument();
nLines = document.GetLines();
for( y = 1; y <= nLines; ++y ) {
    str = document.GetLine( y );   // retrieve an URL at a line
    if( str.length != 0 ) {
        document.selection.OpenLink();
        Sleep( 5000 );  // wait for the browser to become active and show the webpage completely

        shell.SendKeys( "{LWIN DOWN}{PRTSC}{LWIN UP}" );
        Sleep( 500 );
        
        shell.SendKeys( "%{F4}" );  // Press Alt+F4 to close web browser
        Sleep( 500 );
    }
    document.selection.LineDown(false,1);
}
alert( "Finished saving screenshots" );
```

5. You will see screenshots saved in your personal `Pictures/Screenshots` folder. Note this folder path, and the first file name (and the index number). For example, if the file name is `Screenshot (13).png`, the index number is `13`.
6. Copy the macro below to `Screenshot3.jsee`, and correct the folder name (`sFolder`) and index number (`nIndex`). If you are using non-English Windows and the file name is not `Screenshot (...).png`, you might also need to correct the file name (`sFile1`). Open the same text file with URLs, and then run this macro.

`Screenshot3.jsee`

```
sFolder = "C:\\Users\\...\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\";  // Screenshots folder where files are saved on [Win]+[PrintScrn]. Use double-backslashes "\\".
sFile1 = "Screenshot (";   // screenshot file name before index number
nIndex = 13;               // index number of first screenshot, for example, 13 for Screenshot (13).png
sFile2 = ").png";          // screenshot file name after index number

fso = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );

document.selection.StartOfDocument();
nLines = document.GetLines();
for( y = 1; y <= nLines; ++y ) {
    str = document.GetLine( y );   // retrieve an URL at a line
    if( str.length != 0 ) {
        str = str.replace("http://", "");  // remove "http://" and "https://"
        str = str.replace("https://", "");
        if( str.charAt( str.length - 1 ) == '/' ) {  // remove the last slash character
            str = str.substr( 0, str.length - 1 );
        }
        str = str.replace(/[/<>:\\|?*\"]/g, "-");   // replace invalid characters with "-"
        str += ".png";   // append ".png"
        
        sSrc = sFolder + sFile1 + nIndex + sFile2;
        sDest = sFolder + str;
        fso.MoveFile( sSrc, sDest );
    }
    document.selection.LineDown(false,1);
    ++nIndex;
}
alert( "Finished renaming screenshots" );
```

Comment: I followed all the steps; but i think i'm making a mistake.
Or something is missing in the macro.
I present a small video of the steps.

**Problems I encountered:** Page opens; but it doesn't save the pictures.
Also, if possible, add the following to the macro:

The screen will be enlarged and switched to full screen mode. **Note:** What I'm talking about at this point is the action performed with the `F11` key.
Wait `7 seconds` for the text `Press the F11 key to exit full screen` disappears on the screen.

Video: [link](https://disk.yandex.com.tr/i/7SDEIr_bwbP59A)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please copy the macro again. The updated macro will close the Snipping Tools and web browser each time it takes a screenshot. Please don't maximize the EmEditor window. I am not sure if the `F11` key works for the Full Screen. (Maximize window means click the `□` button on the upper right corner of a window.)

Comment: I updated the macro.
The `Macro` just turns off `Snipping Tool`.
It does not close the browser.
But the main problem is that it still doesn't save the screenshot.

And the macro only opens the first two lines.
It never opened the `Google` link.
I added an additional link.
It also opened it; but it didn't open the last link.
I guess it doesn't see the last line.

I was wondering if we could add this to the macro.

`"Open browser"`
`"Press F11"`
`"Wait 7 seconds"`
`"Then open Snipping Tool".`

Comment: I'm sorry the first method wasn't reliable. I added the second method to my answer, and it should be more robust and faster.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry; All you do is help and that's enough.
I have successfully taken screenshots.
But; I followed every step; but "Screenshot3.jsee" gave the following error.
**[Error Picture](https://disk.yandex.com.tr/i/asfr9rFSBeI26Q)**

Comment: Do these macros work for you? I'm starting to wonder if the problem is with the computer.

Comment: Please make sure `sFolder` and `sFile1` and `nIndex` are correct and exist. A backslash needs to be escaped as double-backslashes. `sFolder` needs to be terminated with double-backslashes.

Comment: I changed all the `"\" signs in the file path to "\\"` and it was resolved.

The only problem is that both macros don't execute the last line.
But; this is not a big deal.
For this, I can reach the solution by adding an additional link to the last line.

And finally...
I studied the code a bit and proceeded with straight logic;
and I added `F11` to the macro. And it worked successfully.

Thank you once again for your interest and all your help.
Good thing there is EmEditor.

Comment: The last line might not work if it is not terminated by a newline. If you want to include the last line without a newline, you can replace `y < nLines` with `y <= nLines`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It wasn't a big deal; but thank you.
I appreciate that you listen to the problems related to your program with interest and that you bring to an end every question sent to you, together with its solutions.
I've seen very few people do this. I appreciate.