# Take screenshot with high quality selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to take snapshot of specific element in the page using selenium VBA and what I am searching for is to set the snapshot to get the high quality as possible as I can.
I tried

```
.Window.SetSize 3700, 800
```

And also I tried

```
.ExecuteScript ("document.body.style.zoom='250%'")
```

The last line gives me empty picture. I don't know why ..?

Any ideas of how to get high quality pictures using screenshots?

Comment: Maybe something from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10760645/5720144)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use selenium and I want to take screenshot for specific element not for the whole page. This is not the problem. The problem with me is that the picture produced is not in high quality..

Comment: Any ideas experts .. I have searched a lot and found nothing till now